# Zabbix Agent Active cannot establish TCP connection to Zabbix Server

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

> active check configuration update from [192.168.100.197:10051] started to fail (cannot connect to [[192.168.100.197]:10051]: (null))

Comment: Please add some more description to the your post.

Comment: Besides being very sparse, there's unlikely much that can be helped with here - it's not a programming-related question, and the error is rather clear: `cannot connect to [[192.168.100.197]:10051]`.

Comment: Consider a migration of this question to ServerFault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your Zabbix Server is able to telnet with the Zabbix Agent at 10051 port. If not then please check your network policies and enable the connection for the same. And if you are able to do Telnet with the same then please attach the logs that are given by Both Zabbix Server and Zabbix Agent so that i may be able to reproduce the issue to solve it.